# Holding a card by accident

Tags: cribbage

What happens if you did not realize you could have laid a card down, and used it later in the game?

For instance player one lays a 2, player 2 a Q, player 3 a 6, player 4 a 6, then four goes, so player four moves one; but then at the end of the game noticed on the last round player four could have put down another six that she had in her hand. How would you play that six? Would you be allowed to use it, or would it be a dead card?

Answer (score 3):

According to the ACC's [tournament rule 7.3](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/rule7.asp#section3), on reneging:

> Any cards played after the renege occurs or the pegging of a "go" shall be retrieved by both players, and any points pegged (or scored) are retracted. The non-offending player receives two points for each card that singly could have been played (judges confirm number of cards). The nonoffending player decides if the reneged card(s) will be dead or played. Play continues, and all cards in both hands and crib are counted.

In your example, the play would be brought back to the point of the incorrect go call, the non-offending team would peg two points, and then decide whether or not the remaining six would get to be played.  The scoring of the hands would be unaffected.